# Update mini cart in language change

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I am facing an issue. When I am adding a product in the cart everythings works fine. But If I Change the language (wpml) when I already have some products in the cart, it doesnt translate the mini cart. If I add another product, in the new languange, mini cart gets translated but the first product is still in the previous language. Any thoughts?